# How does this dice rolling circuit work?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, circuit-protection

I'm having trouble understanding how this whole circuit works. I am just a beginner trying to challenge myself but I can't seem to be able to.

[image]

Comment: What has your analysis led you to so far? Do you know what the 4510B and 4511B do?

Comment: I suggest that indeed you look up what the 4510 and 4511 ICs do (read their datasheets). Also search for other "dice rolling" circuits. You got this circuit from somewhere and maybe how the circuit works isn't explained there. There are other similar circuits some if which do have an explanation, I suggest having a look at those.

Comment: Some hints, because I recall a similar circuit from many years ago. The pin names don't match 4510 datasheets I've seen, which makes it a little harder to read, but note the use of L1/2/4/8 (a.k.a. PL0--3) combined with LD (PL) and  the rollover pin C (TC).  Then note the 25Hz clock signal

Comment: Cycled countdown from 6 to 0.

Comment: you can't seem to be able to challenge yourself?

Comment: It is not random but assumes it is too fast to predict which number it stops at as it loads 0110=6 and counts down U/D=0, when Carry =1 at terminal count = 0000 for down

Comment: I agree with @jsotola.  You appear to be challenged!  Go to the datasheets!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are being misled by the labels. Think of the "RESET" as RUN(0) and STOP(1).

If you apply a 0 to that line, the 4510 will run at 25 Hz (faster than your eye can see),and when you set it to 1 the counter will stop.

There is no "reset" in the usual sense.